# Refresh UpdatePanel after a "File Download" dialog Box

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, response.write

I have a User control inside an Update Panel. I trigger a Export to excel from inside this user control on button click. Everything works fine. I get the File Download box. When the "File Download" box is closed, I want the updatepanel to post back or refresh.

This is because of the following,

I trigger a "Please wait" div in the User control, for every server submit event. Now, when the Export button is clicked, the div showwait is thrown. But after File Download, there is no postback and the control does not come back to the server. Hence the Stopwait div is not involved at all.

How do i make the update panel post back after closing "File Download" box is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this. When the export button is clicked, I called onclientclick method and set a javascript variable indicator to 1.

On showwait method, if ind is 1 i dont show the wait message. And then reset the indicator inside the method.

Hence not wait message only for Export button click! :)